How to style a Button with a background which animates to disappears when pressed?
I got this button now:

When it's pressed, I want the 'background' to be removed, like this:

How would I do that? I can not get it to work. I am now adding the background by using a ZStack which is also not that nice because I need to initialize the Button twice.
This is a reproduction path:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct TestButton<V: View>: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme

    let content: V
    var foregroundStyle: Color? = nil

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {} ) {
                content
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 255/255))
            .applyDefaultCornerRadius()
            .offset(y: 5)

            Button(action: {}) {
                content
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .applyDefaultCornerRadius()
            .foregroundStyle(foregroundStyle ?? (colorScheme == .light ? Color.white : Color.black))
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestButton(content: Text(verbatim: "Test"))
}


To apply different styling when a button is pressed, you need to define your own ButtonStyle.
For your example, it works well to change TestButton from a generic Button wrapper into a ButtonStyle. Use an .animation modifier if you want to control the actual animation. The speed of the animation can depend on the pressed state - you might want the animation to go slower when lifting the press.
struct TestButton: ButtonStyle {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme
    var foregroundStyle: Color? = nil

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundStyle(foregroundStyle ?? (colorScheme == .light ? Color.white : Color.black))
            .padding(10)
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .stroke(foregroundStyle ?? (colorScheme == .light ? Color.black : Color.white))
            }
            .offset(y: configuration.isPressed ? 0 : -5)
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                    .fill(Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 255/255))
                    .stroke(Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 255/255))
            }
            .animation(
                .spring(duration: configuration.isPressed ? 0.05 : 0.2),
                value: configuration.isPressed
            )
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {} label: {
            Text("Test")
        }
        .buttonStyle(TestButton())
    }
}



This is really good, thanks a lot!!
